# Include CSS file or CSS Style in HTML

Tags: html, css

If I use css code directly inside of the html code it works.If I use by linking css file inside of the html by  tag it is not working.But I tried with ffox viewsource and link for css redirects to the perfect CSS.Please enlight me in this Case.Thanks in Advance.

CSS(POStyle.css) File included like this in HTML :

```
 <link href="$contextpath/css/yes/POStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

POStyle.css has

```
.popupCSS td, .popupCSS td
    {
         border:1px solid black;
         background-color:#EAF2FB;
         color : red;
    }
```

CSS inside the html directly :

```
<style type="text/css">
.popupCSS td, .popupCSS td
    {
         border:1px solid black;
         background-color:#EAF2FB;
         color : red;
    }   
</style>
```

Comment: $contextpath  may be smarty variable

Comment: What's `$contextpath`'s value?

Comment: no problem with contextpath value it works.problem with the html only .Because from view source and click on the link it goes to the real css file.

Answer (score 1):

When using:

`<link href="$contextpath/css/yes/POStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`

The browser uses the string literal `$contextpath/css/yes/POStyle.css` to request the CSS file.  There is no replacement that occurs as you would expect in JSP files or some other view technology.

You must use either an absolute or relative url to the file:

**Relative**

```
<link href="../css/yes/POStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

**Absolute**

`<link href="http:/www.mydomain.com/context/css/yes/POStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`

Comment: I tried by all these things but nothing works contextpath come perfectly no problem with that.even after giving full path like this no use <link href="http://localhost:8080/rdn_yes_splitchg/css/yes/POStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>

Answer (score 0):

Use `{$contextpath}` instead of `$contextpath`. It is a smarty variable.